# How to get total videos in YouTube with YouTube API in PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api

i've got the PHP codes to get number of views in my YouTube videos:

```
$xdoc = new DomDocument;
$xdoc->Load('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/myUserName');
$ytstat = $xdoc->getElementsByTagName('statistics')->item(0);
$total_views = $ytstat->getAttribute(totalUploadViews);
```

Now how to get total uploaded videos? Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly will prefer to use the JSON format of YouTube API v2:

```
<?php

$username = 'username';
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents(
    "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/$username?v=2&alt=json"));
$uploads = json_decode(file_get_contents(
    "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/$username/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=0"));
printf("Total uploads: %d\nTotal views: %d\n",
    $uploads->data->totalItems,
    $user->entry->{'yt$statistics'}->totalUploadViews);
```

Even better, you might want to use the new YouTube API v3 which reports both info in a single request. To use the new API you'll have to get an API key on [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) and further enable the YouTube Data API v3. Here's the YouTube API v3 code:

```
<?php

$username = 'username';
$api_key = 'your-api-key';
$channel = json_decode(file_get_contents(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=$username&key=$api_key"));
printf("Total uploads: %d\nTotal views: %d\n",
    $channel->items->statistics->videoCount,
    $channel->items->statistics->viewCount);
```

Further info:

- [YouTube API Reference 3.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/)
- [YouTube API Reference Guide 2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference)

Comment: great solution, it works. thank Paulo :) sorry can't vote up because my reputation is not enough yet.

Comment: @ljn You're welcome! You can accept the answer anyway, if you think it solves your problem. :)